# Red/write image from Array

Tags: java

I am reading some images from a JList "desList" like follow:

```
public class DualListBox extends JPanel { 
ArrayList<String> nombreArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
private class compareListener implements ActionListener {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
     metodo m = new metodo();
        if (destList.getSelectedIndex()==-1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "YOU MUST SELECT AN IMAGE", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);           
        }else{           
            model = destList.getModel();             
            for(int i=0; i < model.getSize(); i++){
               lista =  (String) model.getElementAt(i);                
               nombreArrayList.add(i, lista); 
               System.out.println(nombreArrayList.get(i)); //HERE A GOT ALL IMAGES AND PRINT OUT WITHOUT PROBLEM
            }             
         m.test(); //HERE I CALL ANOTHER CLASS WITHOUT PROBLEM
        }
    }
  }
}

public class LeftSide extends JPanel { //THIS IS MY ANOTHER CLASS
public LeftSide() {
setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    Border compound1 = null, compound2;
    Border redline = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red);

    c.gridx = 1;  
    c.gridy = 0;         

    final ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon ("Historial_salidas/Bordes/Original Image.jpg"); //HERE IAM USING AN ABSOLUTELY PATH BUT IN REAL A NEED TO PUT THE FIRST IMAGE READED FROM "nombreArrayList"
    final Icon icono = new ImageIcon(icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(130, 130, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)); 

    compound2 = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(redline, compound1);
    one.setBorder(compound2);      

    one.setIcon(icono);
    one.repaint();
    left.add(one);
    add(left, c);
```

The problem is when I try to put the images from "nombreArrayList" to my another class in 3 diferrents JLabel, in this example "one" is my first JLbael. Any Help?

Comment: You didn't mentioned the problem you are facing...

Comment: qwerty, I did, but in any case I put it again: I am reading some images from a JList "desList" like the first code, The problem is when I try to put the images readed from "nombreArrayList" to my another class in 3 differents JLabel, in this example "one" is my first JLbael. Any Help?